# How could I adapt this code for removing music from specific Itunes playlist

Tags: applescript, itunes, playlist

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in (get file tracks of library playlist 1)
        if location of t is missing value then delete t

    end repeat


end tell
```

Hello dear community,

Anybody knows how could I adapt this code above to make a track being removed from a given playlist.
But not in the case when it is deleted from the hard drive (like it is now , with the "missing value") but that it would be removed if the location of the file changes on the hard drive.
I thought of some command like "changed value" for location of t, but sadly didnt work.

I hope I made myself clear enough. If not, I could try better :)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete playlist items whose files have been moved to another directory since a certain date, you can do something like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in (get tracks of playlist "playlist name")
        do shell script "mdls -rnkMDItemDateAdded " & quoted form of (POSIX path of (get location of t)) & "|cut -d' ' -f1"
        if result > "2018-01-01" then delete t
    end repeat
end tell
```

The script above only deletes each track from the specified playlist and not from the whole iTunes library.

"Date added" is the date when a file was last moved or first indexed, so the script above also applies to files which were created or first indexed by Spotlight after the specified date. `mdimport -A` (which lists all metadata attributes) describes `kMDItemDateAdded` as `Date when this item was last moved`:

```
$ mdimport -A|grep added
'kMDItemDateAdded'      'Date added'        'Date when this item was last moved'        'dateadded, added, date'
```

If you want to delete the items on a playlist whose files are not in the specified directory, you can use a script like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with t in (get tracks of playlist "playlist name")
        location of t
        tell application "Finder" to POSIX path of (folder of file result as alias)
        if result is not "/Users/username/folder" then delete t
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear!